# When writing custom language definitons for Sublime Text 2, which theme items are safe to assume? Or should I be writing a theme as well?

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm writing a new language syntax definition for syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 2. Never having done this before, I've been looking through some theme definitions to see which "theme items" are standard, so as to make my syntax highlighting work well with lots of different themes. But I've found there's basically no standard even for the built in themes!

However, there are some pretty common ones, as far as I can tell: Comment, String, Constant, Keyword, Variable, Support, Storage...

But not all of them even have all of these. It looks like maybe only Comment and String are used in all the themes.

Am I missing any big ones that have widespread theme support? Is there a specification or guideline anywhere for these sorts of things? Or are themes assumed to be at least somewhat language-specific, and I should maybe be writing a new theme to go along with this language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a fair amount of [theme development work](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon.tmTheme) trying to get something that works across a broad range of languages, and I can pretty safely say that there is very little standardization. Yes, there is the TextMate Language Grammar's [Naming Conventions](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#naming_conventions) guide, but there is a ***lot*** of leeway within those base scopes. For example, when you write

```
def my_function(self):
```

in Python, the full scope for `my_function` is

```
source.python meta.function.python entity.name.function.python
```

whereas the same line in Ruby (without the colon) is

```
source.ruby meta.function.method.with-arguments.ruby entity.name.function.ruby
```

Not so different if you have your `function` scope selector in your theme as

```
{meta.function entity.name.function}
```

but how about the `def` keyword? In Python it's `storage.type.function.python`, but in Ruby it's `keyword.control.def.ruby`. I could go on, but I think you've got the idea :)

So, what do you do about it? Well, you could just wing it, and pick scopes that appeal to you personally, then design a theme to go with it. All fine and good, but people tend to be pretty particular about their themes, and may not like your color choices or whatnot. Another option is wing it, but document your scopes clearly and consistently, so people can modify their own themes (if needed). Third, and probably best IMO, would be to try and stay as close as possible to a popular existing language, preferably one that's similar yours, so the scopes translate as well as possible. For example, if you were making a language definition for PowerShell, you'd want to copy as much as possible from the Bash/Shell Script language definition.

Good luck with your work, and please feel free to look around my Neon theme that I linked to above. It covers a lot of languages generally, and several specifically (it's quite customized for Python, and I'm adding to the Ruby functionality currently), so hopefully you can get some ideas from there.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I suspected. I ended up going with your third way of staying close to an existing popular language. It's still a work in progress, and I'll check out your Neon theme.

Answer (score 4):

No need! These mysterious entities which you call "theme items" ("scopes" in the [Unofficial Sublime Text Documentation Syntax Definition Tutorial](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html), a guide that also suggests the usage of the excellent [PackageDev Plugin](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev)) are in fact regulated by the [Naming Conventions section](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#naming_conventions) of the indispensable (but difficult to find) [TextMate Language Grammars manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars). Read it, and all of your questions should be answered.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the unofficial documentation; I hadn't encountered that yet.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problems, and I also noticed that there are no real standards (except [Naming conventions of TextMates Language Grammars Chapter](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars.html).  I have written [SyntaxHighlightTools](https://bitbucket.org/klorenz/syntaxhighlighttools) for easing this a bit (Installable using PackageControl).

Using this toolset, you can either create a new theme file from collecting scope-names from all language files, or you can can open those language files you want your theme work with, in one window and then generate your new theme file.  You can also open one or more theme files for input, whose rules will be
used as base for your new one.

I am interested in feedback, if this is suitable.

Textmate language grammar section is covering not all Sublime Text 2 scopes. There is e.g. punctuation.* which is commonly used in Sublime Text, but not mentioned in this document.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, but I'll check this out. Thanks!

Comment: I really like this tool; it's making my life a lot easier.